# Remove whitespaces from beginning and end of each line in a file in python

Tags: python, file, removing-whitespace

I am trying to read some numbers from a file and store them into an array called `numbers`.
I use `strip()` for each line to remove the `\n` at the end of each line. I also use `split(' ')` for each line to remove the spaces between the numbers.

The problem is that in the input file the first character on the line and the last character on the line are spaces. How can I erase them?

This is my code:

```
def read_from_file():
    f = open('input_file.txt')
    numbers = []
    for eachLine in f:
        line = eachLine.strip()
        for x in eachLine.split(' '):
            line2 = int(x)
            numbers.append(line2)
    f.close()
    print numbers
```

This is the text file, where the underscores are spaces:

```
_9 5_
_2 3 1 5 4_
_2 1 5_
_1 1_
_2 1 2_
_2 2 3_
_2 3 4_
_3 3 4 5_
_2 4 5_
_2 1 5_
_3 1 2 5_
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strip()` already removes the spaces from both ends. The error is in the line:

```
for x in eachLine.split(' '):
```

You should use `line` and not `eachLine` in the `for`.

To avoid this kind of problems you could avoid using the intermediate variable at all:

```
for line in f:
    for x in line.strip().split():
        # do stuff
```

Note that calling `split()` without arguments splits on *any* sequence of whitespace, which is usually what you want. See:

```
>>> 'a  b c d'.split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> 'a  b c d'.split(' ')
['a', '', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Note the empty string of the last result. `split(' ')` splits on every *single* whitespace.

Comment: You could use `for line in (line.strip() for line in f):`, so there's no need to do the stripping in the loop.

Comment: @Bakuriu I have changed my code so that I don't use the intermediate variable and I have changed `split(' ')` to `split()`. Now it's working as it should. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("myfile.txt") as lines:
    for line in lines:
        print line.strip()
```

Use [`.strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove leading and trailing whitespace